# How can shift page number all the way to the edge of the margin in Excel 2007?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, page-numbers, shift

I need to move page number from here

[image]

to here

[image]

Is that possible in Excel 2007? I'm not even sure what to search. To be clear, I know how create page numbers and how to position them in the basic sense. But I need page number to be at the far edge of the corner as possible. Any Ideas?

Comment: It seems related to the Margins in Page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to printing's `Page Setup` and choose the third tab, labelled `Header/Footer`. In the center of the tab's material, click on the button `Custom Footer`.

The `Footer` dialog will open and at its bottom are three little "panes." The rightmost one is labelled `Right section`. It is the one to click in.

Type anything and notice that it formats itself from the right edge toward the center. This is what you want, so make the entry you desire for your page number display.

As implied in the "pane" it will be formatted up against the right edge of your page, consistent with whatever margin you have.

I haven't a copy of Excel 2007 to test it works in it, but this has been the way as long as I can remember this ability in page formatting. I go back to the 1991 edition of Excel sold, though I used Quattro Pro more for a couple years after buying it.

If I have misinterpreted your pictures, and what you want is to actually display this page number outside your otherwise required margins, footers cannot do it for you.

You CAN do such on the sheet itself, with a column outside the rest of the print area you would have used, and if anything would bleed over into it, you can fill each cell other than the page number cell with something, perhaps a space or `=""`. Of course, you will have to do the work of figuring the page and "of pages" parts yourself.

Side note:  of course, the center footer centers the material entered there and the left footer formats from the left. Both are kind of exactly expected and so perhaps seldom noticed. That makes it happening in the right footer pane something unexpected.

Comment: Yea, I guess that will work. But it's not exactly the solution I was looking for. If I don't get anything else in a week, ill just make this the answer. I figured there maybe a way to do it via excel programming of some kind or something.